# Why is It make error? I want to make moving average code in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int *a, *x;
    int n, k;
    int i;                              //index
    int sum=0, avg=0;

    a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    if(a==NULL)
        printf("error\n");
    x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    if(x==NULL)
       printf("error\n");

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    sum=0;
    avg=0;


    for(i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        sum=sum+a[i];
        avg=sum/(i+1)+0.5;
        x[i]=avg;
    }
    for(i=k; i<n; i++)
    {
        sum=sum-a[i-3]+a[i];
        avg=sum/3+0.5;
        x[i]=avg;
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", x[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to make moving average code in C.
and I made the code but it has still error :(
I think I broke the basic rule in C but I don't know what it is ...
Plz help me
Let me show you what I want to make

Input example

```
6 3                                                   
1 3 2 10 6 8
```

Output

```
1 2 2 5 6 8
```

Input example 2

```
9 4                                
2 7 4 5 6 8 2 8 13
```

Output example

```
2 5 4 5 6 6 5 6 8
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "error" you get. Is it a build error? Wrong results? Crashes? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I also recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Your example inputs appear to be intended to accept values for both n and k; you have no code to accept these values and are then using initialised values.  There is no "basic rule of C" that you have broken - it compiles, so that cannot be true.  You may have other semantic errors and examples of ill-advised coding practice, and a poorly designed algorithm, but that is a different matter.  The compiler will save you from the "basic rule" errors by not compiling and reporting errors.

Answer (score 2):

The primary problem is in

```
  a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

where `n` is unitialized. It contains indeterminate value. The behavior is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1,

> [...] If
>   the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been
>   declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object
>   is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been
>   performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.

That said, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

That said, there are couple of more things

- Take care (*beware*) of uninitialized variables, they are source of many problems. Initialize or assign them before they are used. Turn up your compiler warning settings, they will help you out.
- `int main()` better be `int main(void)` for a hosted environment, unless you have a specialized environment/ compiler which has explicit support for `int main()`.
- On the NULL check, in case of failure, only printing the error is not sufficient, you should also discontinue the program.
- `printf("some_string");` is not a good practice. If you do not have to have a conversion specification required, go with `puts()`.

Comment: +1, Additionally, you could also recommend that `printf("Error");` is not the apt and ideal way to handle that error. OP could always `return` if nothing else.

Comment: @WedaPashi True indeed. Let me update.

Comment: Also, by the time this `for(i=0; i<k; i++)` loop us invoked, `k` in uninitialized. It might loop forever.

Comment: @WedaPashi Now it should be covered. :)

Comment: Errors should be reported on `stderr` — it is called standard error for a reason!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Absolutely, that's the prescribed way. I took this case as an attempt to insert _debug messages_ and did not emphasis on that part, however, you are very correct!!